# How do you differentiate "soft" CC from "hard" CC?

Tags: league-of-legends, terminology

This question is about the difference about what is generally called "soft" CC and what is referred to as "hard" CC. I can of course feel the difference to some extent : slows are soft and stuns are hard, obviously. However, I'm hesitating about silence, for exemple. I was wondering if there was a strict definition for that.

To sum it up : **is there a clear definition of what is soft CC and what is hard CC ?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are many different types of CC - *Crowd Control* - and [LOL Wiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Crowd_control) lays it out quite nicely

> **Loss of Control** - *Crowd controls are grouped into one of two categories depending on whether or not the effect removes total control of the player's character. Hard CC completely removes all control of a character, while soft CC only partially removes it.*
>
> *Hard CC*
>
> 1. Airborne
> 2. Forced Action
> 3. Stasis
> 4. Stun
> 5. Suppression
> 6. Suspension
>
> *Soft CC*
>
> 1. Blind
> 2. Disarm
> 3. Root/Snare
> 4. Silence
> 5. Slow

---

> **Disruption** - *Crowd controls are grouped into one of two categories depending on whether or not the effect disrupts a channeled ability (such as Karthus Karthus's Requiem and Katarina Katarina's Death Lotus). Hard CC will disrupt channels, while soft CC will not.*
>
> *Hard CC*
>
> 1. Airborne
> 2. Forced Action
> 3. Silence
> 4. Stun
> 5. Suppression
> 6. Suspension
>
> *Soft CC*
>
> 1. Blind
> 2. Disarm
> 3. Root/Snare
> 4. Slow

---

> **Movement** - *Crowd controls are grouped into one of two categories depending on whether or not they restrict movement. Hard CCs prevent all forms of movement, while soft CCs do not.*
>
> *Hard CC*
>
> 1. Airborne
> 2. Forced Action
> 3. Root/Snare
> 4. Stasis
> 5. Suppression
> 6. Suspension
>
> *Soft CC*
>
> 1. Blind
> 2. Disarm
> 3. Silence
> 4. Slow

Comment: That's basically giving different definitions depending on what degree of liberty is considered. I was looking for a global definition, but that's very interesting nonetheless !

Comment: @Sheldonator It's because there is no global definition. A lot of it depends on the champs being played. For example, once Katarina ults, a snare (which is typically considered "hard" CC) doesn't really help since it does not stop Kat's ult. A silence ("soft" CC), however, shut her down completely. On the other hand, any marksman (Caitlyn, Jinx, Lucian, etc.) is still a high threat while silenced since they can still auto-attack... but a snare leaves them wide open to being eaten alive.

Comment: True. Welp, I guess that completes your answer.

Comment: Some CCs fit into the "Hard" definition regardless of which one is chosen, e.g. Airborne. In fact most of them do.

Comment: You missed one for Hard CC.  You kill the dude.

Answer (score 6):

Each game develops its own terminology.
And even within each game, different people have different definitions of said terminology.
More specific term(s) **would/could** be: stun, root, snare, mez (and many many more)

But in general.
**"Hard CC"**
Complete loss of control over your character. This means you cannot move, cast spells or attack in any way for the duration of the stun. In some cases, your characters gets moved under control of another player (pulled, pushed)

**"Soft CC"**
Any form of debuff that restricts your movement (slow or root) and/or* restricts your attacks (unable to casts spells or heal or auto attack).

- A root **and** a restriction on attacking would ofcourse result in a hard CC.

Answer (score 1):

I've most often seen "hard" and "soft" CC referring to whether the ability prevents movement or not. Soft CC is usually implied to be any type of CC that still allows a champion to move around. As you mentioned, slows are the most common type of soft CC, since they reduce the movement speed of enemy champions but still allow them to get away using movement skills (or by getting lucky and being able to outrun the chaser, despite the slow).

Hard CC stops movement completely (or forces movement in a specific way). Stuns are the obvious example of hard CC, but this category also includes knockups/displacement (which cannot be cleansed or QSS'd, by the way), snares, and roots. Many assassin type champions are directly countered by hard CC - Master Yi, for example, relies entirely on getting close to his target and auto-attacking them, which he can't do if he simply can't move.